# error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android

I keep receiving this error when building my APK:
../AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/myproject/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:173: error: unexpected element  found in .

I got an intent-fiter that get automatically added outside of an activity  in the intermediate androidmanifest.xml file

I start to see that error after I've upgraded to Android studio 3.3.2 or the API Level from 25 to 28 (not sure which one)

Any idea where I should look to?

Thank's

Comment: look at `Manifest.xml` and then move that `intent-filter` into an `activity` tag.

Comment: post mainfest..

Comment: I come accross this `Manifest.xml` error of mispalced intent-filter tag outside the activty while updating gradle plugin from(2.2.3) to latest android plugin( `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4`). Intent-filter tag decleration outside of the activity or service tag causes this error https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#aapt2_changes

Comment: @Martin. - The new intent-filter keep coming back again and again (not in my main androidmanifest.xml but here in the ../AndroidStudioProjects/myproject/myproject/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml)